# Sort by Title in Core Service for Categories

Tags: 2013, core-service

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and using the Core Service to retrieve all the categories in the SDL Tridion system. Below is my code:

```
TaxonomiesFilterData taxFilter = new TaxonomiesFilterData();
taxFilter.SortExpression = "Title";
XElement items = client.GetListXml("tcm:0-10-1", taxFilter);
```

Here `client` is a `SessionAwareCoreServiceClient` client and `tcm:0-10-1` is a valid Publication ID

I am able to retrieve all the categories in the publication successfully, however, the issue is that they are not in a Sorted order as I wish to get them in sorted by their title (same as it happens in the CME).

Further, I have even tried using the Item Selector Community extension (created by Bart) but I am also getting the same result (non-sorted list of categories).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
var items = client.GetList("tcm:0-10-1", taxFilter);
```

And then

```
var orderedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i.Title);
```

Comment: Thanks; although I was looking for some way to sort this out through the core service itself - I wish SortExpression or something like that would be of some help. I really do not wish to sort it after retrieving the result.

Comment: Why? It will even be faster. And we are talking about relatively small amount of items. I doubt you have more than few hundred categories. Also, as it's Linq it will only sort it when necessary

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if `taxFilter.SortExpression = "Title";` works at all. 
I have tried it with `TaxonomiesFilterData`  and `CategoriesFilterData` and its not working like above (setting a field name as a sort expression ).

But if you want to use `GetListXml` not `GetList` as suggested in anothee answer by @user978511, you can use `CategoriesFilterData` inplace of `TaxonomiesFilterData`, as it returns the categories sorted by title by default.

I know its not the best option but could be useful.